# Combining two lists of objects on particular attributes

Tags: java, list

I have 2 lists of ReportItem objects:

```
tcItems [ReportItem [date=2014-07-11 08:00:00.000,operator=Vodafone,country=Irl,blocked=1,total=1,uniqTriggeredCount=1,], ReportItem [date=2014-07-11 08:00:00.000,operator=TMob,country=UK,blocked=2,total=4,uniqTriggeredCount=3,]]
fcItems [ReportItem [date=2014-07-11 08:00:00.000,filterid=1,country=Irl,operator=Vodafone,triggered=0,blocked=0,analysis=3,], ReportItem [date=2014-07-11 08:00:00.000,filterid=1,country=UK,operator=TMob,triggered=0,blocked=5,analysis=0,], ReportItem [date=2014-07-11 08:00:00.000,filterid=2,country=UK,operator=TMob,triggered=0,blocked=4,analysis=0,]]
```

I want to create a new list from the two lists such that any reportItem in tcItems that has the same date, country and operator as a reportItem in fcItems gets a reportItem object in the new list with combined attributes of the two. In the above example I want:

```
newReportItems [ReportItem  [date=2014-07-11 08:00:00.000,operator=Vodafone,country=Irl,blocked=1,total=1,uniqTriggeredCount=1,[filterid=1,triggered=0,blocked=0,analysis=3],],  ReportItem [date=2014-07-11 08:00:00.000,operator=TMob,country=UK,blocked=2,total=4,uniqTriggeredCount=3,[filterid=1,triggered=0,blocked=5,analysis=0],[filterid=2,triggered=0,blocked=4,analysis=0],]
```

Note that fcItems can have multiple filterIds, triggereds, blockeds and analysises.

I have looked but can not find a way to merge these two lists of objects. Please help

Comment: ohhh Please format your question. It is hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 steps:

1) Override `ReportItem`'s `equals` method to return true when compared with another ReportItem which has the same date, country and operator.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof ReportItem) {
        ReportItem ri = (ReportItem) o;
        if (this.getDate().equals(ri.getDate()) && ... // compare other attributes) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

1b) If you cannot modify ReportItem, write a `Comparator<ReportItem>` which returns 0 in its `compare` method for matching ReportItems.

2) Iterate through tcItems and for each item check if it is contained in fcItems (using equals or the comparator). If it is, take both `ReportItems` and combine them as you wish

```
for (ReportItem ri : tcItems) {
    ReportItem matchingRI = findMatchingRI(ri);
    if (matchingRI != null) {
        // merge
    }
}

private ReportItem findMatchingRI(ReportItem ri) {
    for (ReportItem fcItem : fcItems) {
         if (fcItem.equals(ri)) 
             return fcItem;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now you could also use Java 8's streaming API with filter/collect, but I will not go into detail about that.